# Variable undeclared

Tags: prolog

I have a function that takes the first item from a list, and checks if that item is one of several items, executes some functions accordingly and recursively executes on the next items on the list.

My trouble is that in line 6, the variable instantiated as the first item of the list is no longer defined, and I have trouble figuring out why.

I just started working with KBSs' so forgive me if my language is incorrect.

```
1 f(L) :- 
2     [F|Ls] = L,
3     (
4        (F = value1 -> ...);
5        (F = value2 -> ...)
6    ) -> f(Ls); format('~w is not a valid action', [F]).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After compiling your code, ask the following query:

```
?- listing(f).

f(L) :-
    (   L=[F|Ls],                              % <== unification IS PART OF the condition!
        (   F=value1
        ->  ...
        ;   F=value2
        ->  ...
        )
    ->  f(Ls)
    ;   format('~w is not a valid action', [F]) % <== when condition fails, unification is UNDONE
    ).
```

As you can see, the unification is part of the condition. Thus, when condition **fails**, the unification is **undone**, turning `F` a **single** variable.

To solve the problem, format the code as follows:

```
f(L) :-
     [F|Ls] = L,                  % <== Now, unification IS NOT PART OF the condition!
     (   (   (F = value1 -> ...)
         ;   (F = value2 -> ...) )
     ->  f(Ls)
     ;   format('~w is not a valid action', [F]) ).
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for the answer! That helps a bunch. I'm not sure how to phrase the following question but, why would the first unification be included with the condition by the compiler? How does the compiler evaluate AND expressions and nest the structures accordingly? If you have any links on the matter that would be appreciated.

Comment: The operator `(,)/2` denotes the logical connective AND and the operator `(;)/2` denotes the logical connective OR. Since `(,)/2` has precedence over `(->)/2` and `(->)/2` has precedence over `(;)/2`, a term `(a, b -> c ; d)` is interpreted as `(((a,b) -> c) ; d)`. You can use predicate `write_canonical/1` to see that. For example, the query `?- write_canonical((a, b -> c ; d)).` shows `;(->(','(a,b),c),d)`.

Answer (score 1):

Example of ->/2 usage:

```
do_something_with_first_elem([Head|_]) :-
    do_something_with_elem(Head).
    
do_something_with_elem(Elem) :-
    ( Elem = a -> writeln('Head is a')
    ; Elem = b -> writeln('Head is b')
    ; Elem = 3 -> writeln('Head is 3 (a number)')
    ; format('~w is not a valid action', [Elem])
    ).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- do_something_with_first_elem([b, c, d]).
Head is b
true.

?- do_something_with_first_elem([z, c, d]).
z is not a valid action
true.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While I appreciate it, it doesn't recursively call the functor on the rest of the list. I was also wondering more specifically what was the logical error within my code as well.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain that an action is wanted on each element of the list, rather than just the first.